# PostgreSQL: Drop in performance with multiple running functions without hardware bottleneck

Tags: postgresql, performance, function

I have simple function, if I run it it takes around 40 second to finish.

```
select * from f_cyklus1(100000000)
```

but if I run this function 8 times in 8 separated instances, meaning all 8 function are running in parallel it takes around 210 to 260 seconds to finish for each of it's instances. Which is a massive drop in performance. I tried to compile it as 8 individual functions and run it again but it had no change in performance.

```
select * from f_cyklus1(100000000); 
select * from f_cyklus2(100000000); 
select * from f_cyklus3(100000000); 
select * from f_cyklus4(100000000); 
select * from f_cyklus5(100000000); 
select * from f_cyklus6(100000000); 
select * from f_cyklus7(100000000); 
select * from f_cyklus8(100000000);
```

So why it takes 40s compare to 210-260s to finish? Our virtual machine has 16 CPUs and physical hardware was at low usage. I was also the only one using the Postgre database at the time of testing.

```
create or replace function f_cyklus1 (p_rozsah int) returns bigint as -- drop function f_cyklus(int)
$body$
declare 

declare 
  v_exc_context        TEXT;
  v_result             INTEGER;

  p_soucet bigint :=0;
begin

for i in 0..p_rozsah
loop
p_soucet = p_soucet + i;
end loop;

return p_soucet;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS v_exc_context = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
    PERFORM main.ut_log('ERR', SQLERRM || ' [SQL State: ' || SQLSTATE || '] Context: ' || v_exc_context );
    RAISE;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

> PostgreSQL 11.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5
>   20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit
>
> Virtual machine: Centos 7 + KVM
>
> HW: 2x AMD EPYC 7351 + 256 GB RAM

Note: I already asked similar question where I thought it was due to asynchronous processing, but this shows the problem is actually in raw Postgres performance, therefore I deleted my former question and asked this new one.

Comment: Can you show the output of `vmstat 1` while you are running the parallel queries?

Comment: here, I marked moment when I started https://files.fm/u/pwm48myx#/view/vmstat.png

Comment: Take the database out of the equation entirely, by running several CPU intensive perl or python (for example) scripts in parallel.  Do they scale the way you think they should all the way up to 16 concurrent processes?

Comment: yes, we tried zip and run it with 1 thread and 16 thread, result was with 16 threads it was 14.6 time faster so the server is not the problem, also my colleague tried to run this example I shown here on his laptop with local database and it was slowing down as well, so I guess anybody can try it with their database and see for themselves

Comment: Why a loop to begin with? What are you trying to test with that useless loop?

Comment: point of that loop was a simple way for anybody to test the performance drop, and loop is the most simplest example I could come up with, loop itself is not the point, the performance drop is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> p_soucet = p_soucet + i;
> ```

Each time you do this, it has to acquire a "snapshot" in which to run the statement, as it uses the regular SQL engine behind the scenes and that always needs to run in snapshot.  Acquiring a snapshot requires a system-wide lock. The more processes you have running simultaneously, the more time they spend fighting to acquire the snapshot, rather than doing useful work.

If you run the function in a transaction which is set to "repeatable read", you will find they scale better because they keep the same snapshot for the duration and keep re-using it.  Of course that might interfere with your real use case.

plpgsql is not really well suited for this kind of work, scaling aside. You can use one of the other pl languages, like plperl or plpythonu.

How expressions are evaluated by main SQL engine is described at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-expressions.html

Snapshots are discussed in general at the docs starting at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html

I am not aware that the interaction between the two are documented anywhere for end users.

Comment: Thank you, it works... however this was just a simple case I made for demonstration, on our database we struggle with performance, just with a few functions running (real daily task which do inserts and updates on tables) we see a massive performance drop while our server has barely any load ... do you have any sources where is this "snapshot" mechanism closely explained, I haven't found anything in documentation so far.

Comment: @Baker I think you have simplified your example to the point it may no longer accurately reflect what the bottleneck is on your real use case.  Or at least, the mitigation would be different. Could you make an example which still uses INSERTs and UPDATEs on a dummy table?

Comment: Unfortunately so far I am unable to replicate it with dummy table inserts/updates, but I can show you two explain analyze of the same query normally it takes 3.5s to finish while when others are running their functions (on different tables so no exclusive locks) it takes 17s for the same query, while CPU and Disk are still at low usage 
https://explain.depesz.com/s/PCCQ  
https://explain.depesz.com/s/wDU8

Comment: @Baker those two queries evaluate vastly different number of rows, checkout out the Parallel Seq Scan on ui_cdc_s5_misto_cas_zdroj_aggregace_zdrobneni.  The nature of the data has changed radically between executions.  I don't think it would matter if the change was running concurrently without something else or was in single-file; it is the change itself that changes the performance.  Also, based on "Heap Blocks: lossy=36864" you could benefit from higher work_mem.

Comment: it was the exact same query, running on the same amount of data .... and I experimented with work_mem but for some reason from certain size of the table postgres stop fully utilize it, if I had smaller table (between 0 to few GB) it got fully cached but if table was around 20GB it did not, even when I set work_mem to 40GB

Comment: @Baker You should probably trust what `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` is telling you.  While the top result returns the same number of rows, the intermediate results like the seq scan mentioned are definitely not.  work_mem doesn't cache data between executions (that is "shared_buffers") it is the private scratch space for each individual execution.